# Ask about passive voice

Tags: word-usage, transitive-verbs

Which is correct?

John F.Kennedy became the 35th president of the USA in 1960-the youngest man ever **was elected**. or the youngest man ever **to be elected**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**the youngest man ever was elected** states that JFK was the youngest man ever, regardless of his status as president. **the youngest man ever to be elected** however states that he was the youngest man ever, in the class of people who have been elected, so take the latter.